# Module build failed after updating Angular Project from 14 to 15

Tags: angular, module

I tried to run my project, but it shows me an error.

```
./src/styles.scss?ngGlobalStyle - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
HookWebpackError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Only 0 arguments allowed, but 1 was passed.
  ┌──> src/material.theme.scss
147│ @include mat-core($fontConfig);
  │ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ invocation
  ╵
  ┌──> node_modules/@angular/material/core/_core.scss
8 │ @mixin core() {
  │        ━━━━━━ declaration
  ╵
  src/material.theme.scss 147:1  core()
  src/material.theme.scss 147:1  @import
  src/styles.scss 5:9            root stylesheet
```

I searched for solutions but didn't find anything

My Versions are

```
"@angular/animations": "^15.1.3",
        "@angular/cdk": "^15.1.3",
        "@angular/common": "^15.1.3",
        "@angular/compiler": "^15.1.3",
        "@angular/core": "^15.1.3",
        "@angular/flex-layout": "^15.0.0-beta.42",
        "@angular/forms": "^15.1.3",
        "@angular/material": "^15.1.3",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "^15.1.3",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^15.1.3",
        "@angular/router": "^15.1.3",
        "angular-material": "^1.2.3",
        "angular-oauth2-oidc": "^15.0.1",
        "lodash": "^4.17.21",
        "moment": "^2.29.1",
        "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
        "tslib": "^2.3.0",
        "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have uploaded the material version to a version compatible with angular 15

In this link you can see the material versions available now:
[Current Material versions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/material?activeTab=versions)

For nagular 15 you must use material 15.

Comment: I edited my question and added my Versions

Comment: Make sure u use the correct version, why do you have angular-material and @angular/material dependencies?